# DiscordJS v14 member.guild.channels.cache.fetch is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm coding a welcome message, that sends automaticly, when someone joins. But when someone joins, an error happens.

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config()
const fs = require("fs")
const { Client, Collection, Intents} = require("discord.js")

const client = new Client({intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING]})
client.commands = new Collection()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')); 
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')); 


commandFiles.forEach((commandFile) => {
    const command = require(`./commands/${commandFile}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
})


eventFiles.forEach((eventFile) => {
    const event = require(`./events/${eventFile}`)
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args))
})


client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! I'm on ${client.guilds.cache.size} guild(s)!`)
    client.user.setActivity({name: "on the SeaMystics Server!", type: "PLAYING"})
})


client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('1155899900161171586').send({
        embeds: [
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Welcome")
                .setDescription(`${member.toString()}` + 'joined the `SeaMysics`-Server')
                .setColor("#4ba511")
                .setTimestamp()]
        });
})

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {

    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if(command) {

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);

            if(interaction.deferred || interaction.replied) {
                interaction.editReply('There was an error while executing this command!')
            }else {
                interaction.reply('There was an error while executing this command!')
            }
        }
    }
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

guildMemberAdd.js

```
const { MessageEmbed, GuildMember } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "guildMemberAdd",

    /**
     * 
     * @param {GuildMember} member
     */

    execute(member) { 
        
        member.guild.channels.cache.fetch("1155899900161171586").send({
            embeds: [
                new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Welcome")
                    .setDescription(`${member.toString()}` + 'joined the `SeaMysics`-Server')
                    .setColor("#4ba511")
                    .setTimestamp()]
            })
        
    }
}
```

I'm using an event handler

This is the error:

> TypeError: member.guild.channels.cache.fetch is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Use `member.guild.channels.fetch()`

Comment: Now I gaet the error:

`TypeError: member.guild.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function`

Comment: (await member.guild.channels.fetch(...)).send(...). Because ...fetch() returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `cache`. Previous answer is correct but needs to be awaited.

```js
const channel = await member.guild.channels.fetch("ID")
channel.send("Hello")
```

Or use cache

```js
member.guild.channels.cache.get("ID")?.send("Hello")
```